# Corrupted files on internal storage (now readonly), how to repair internal storage?

Tags: internal-storage, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have an GT-I9100 with Chameleon.3.0.4 ROM (and ROOT).
Android-Version is: 4.1.2

Since few month, my **internal SD-Card (internal storage, not external SD)** became **readonly**.
I cannot add/edit/delete any files on it anymore.

I noticed corrupted files in `/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/`
(wrong filesizes (each > 3GB) and wrong/unreadable filenames),
which I am unable to delete or fix.

So, I tried to execute `fsck_msdos -y /dev/block/vold/259:3` (as root) via ADB-Shell, which shows me:

```
** /dev/block/vold/259:3

Boot sector contents: 

sectors per cluster:..........64 
number of reserved sectors:...2236 
number of FATs:...............2 
number of sectors are in FAT:.2946 (1473 KB) 
cluster mask (bit):...........32 

first cluster offset..........8000 
cluster size(bytes):..........32768 

hidden sectors:...............0 
number of clusters:...........376963 

volume serial number:.........407a-07d3 
volume label:.................NO NAME    { 0x4f 0x20 0x4e 0x41 0x4d 0x45 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x46} 

** Phase 1 - Read and Compare FATs 
Attempting to allocate 1473 KB for FAT 

Attempting to allocate 1473 KB for FAT

** Phase 2 - Check Cluster Chains

** Phase 3 - Checking Directories

Invalid long filename entry for /Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/�ILES

Remove? yes 
check_dot_dot: '.' absent for /Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/�ILES. 
check_dot_dot: '..' absent for /Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/�ILES.  
Remove? yes 

FSNext block (322159) is correct, NumClusters (376963)

12387 files, 646240 free (20195 clusters) 

***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
```

Which looks good.
But when I re-run this command, I **always** get the same result.
Which shows me, the file system was **not modified**, cause it's readonly.

So, I tried to re-mount the storage in RW-Mode.
Fixing the file system, did not work for me. (`fsck_msdos` couldn't repair the fs)

**Question:**

How to repair the internal storage?

Answer (score -1):

This is an answer to my own question:

I managed to fix this problem (until now), by doing following:

(**NOTE:** Do this at your own risk!)

**01.**  boot into Android and enable USB-Debugging
 **02.**  backup data from SD
 **03.**  update busybox via PlayStore
 **04.**  reboot into recovery mode
 **05.**  mount `system` partition (via recovery tools like CWM)
 **06.**  connect to device via USB + ADB(-Shell)
 **07.**  get internal SD device name (via `mount` which is for me`/dev/block/mmcblk0p11`)
 **08.**  format internal SD (via `mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/block/mmcblk0p11`)
 **09.** check new formatted partition (via `fsck_msdos -y /dev/block/mmcblk0p11`)
 **10.** reboot into Android and check if internal SD is writable again

Until now, my internal SD became writable again!
Of course, all data is gone.

Cheers!

Comment: Why the downvote?!?!